# Can I understand the topology of some smooth 3-manifolds in the following way?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 3d

Consider the smooth 3-manifolds, $M$, which can be 'sliced', i.e. $$M=\bigcup_{t\in I}\Sigma_t$$ where $t$ is a real parameter, $I$ is some interval of the real line, and $\Sigma_t$ is a smooth 2-manifold $\forall t$.

The topology of the 2-manifolds is given entirely by the genus, $g$. Here it is a function of the parameter $t$: $g\equiv g(t)$. It seems to me that the topology of such an $M$ is entirely specified by the function $g(t)$. Is this correct and is it useful?

A typical instance of $g(t)$ might be:

[image]

I should add that at the instances where the genus changes, I expect $\Sigma_t$ to actually be a singular manifold.

Comment: It is false that "The topology of the 2-manifolds is given entirely by the genus, $g$." It's true only once you assume that your manifold is compact, connected and you have information about its orientability.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the assertion "The topology of the 2-manifolds is given entirely by the genus, $g$" is false. It is true under some extra assumptions, namely, that the manifold is connected, compact and, say, orientable (or nonorientable). Thus, let me assume that each $\Sigma_t$ is connected, compact and  orientable.

Next, you wrote the ordinary union, $\bigcup_{t\in I}\Sigma_t$, but you surely meant a disjoint union,
$$
\coprod_{t\in I} \Sigma_t, 
$$
i.e. you forgot to assume that for different values of $t$ the surfaces are disjoint.

However, even with this assumption the conjecture that the topology of $M$ is uniquely determined by the function $t\mapsto g(t)$, where $g(t)$ is the genus of $\Sigma_t$, is false even if you additionally assume that the 3-dimensional manifolds are compact, orientable and connected. Examples are given by various 3-dimensional manifolds fibered over the circle. Up to a homeomorphism, there are infinitely many 3-dimensional manifolds which can be sliced as
$$
\coprod_{t\in I} \Sigma_t, g(t)=1 ~~~\forall t. 
$$
These manifolds are torus bundles over the circle. The interval $I$ in this case is $[0,1)$ and, moreover, in a suitable sense, $\Sigma_t$ depends smoothly on $t$. On the other hand, if you do not assume that surfaces are orientable, there are examples of connected sliced manifolds where the topology of the slices depends on $t$ (switches from orientable to nonorientable and the genus changes as well).

Comment: Ah okay. So this seems to arise due to the topology of the circle (abit like the mobius strip). I wonder if this persists if we require $I$ to strictly be an interval.

Comment: @dennis In my examples $I$ is an interval.

Comment: Didn't you say torus bundle over the circle?

Comment: @dennis: Yes, I did. But to get a partition parameterized by surfaces from a fibration one has to work a bit. Namely: Let $f: M\to S^1$ be a torus bundle over the circle. You can also describe $M$ as the image of $T^2\times [0,1)$ under a continuous bijective map $h$ such that for each $t\in [0,1)$, $h(T^2\times t)$ is one of the fibers (this corresponds to a continuous bijective map $[0,1)\to S^1$) . The latter gives the slicing of $M$.

Comment: Since we're speaking of topology, I think we have to be careful in identifying $S^1$ with $[0,1)$.

Comment: Speaking of bundles, another question I have is, can any smooth 3-mfd be realized as a surface bundle (over some 1 dimensional mfd)?

Comment: @dennis: I am not identifying them, I was saying "continuous bijection", not a homeomorphism. In contrast, in your question, $I$ is just a set, you can as well use any set of cardinality continuum. If you did not mean what you wrote in the original post, you should make it clear.

Comment: Regarding "can any smooth 3-mfd..." I think you do not mean "any", you mean "every" (these are not synonims).  The answer would be negative, the simplest (compact) example is the sphere $S^3$.

Comment: $S^3$ is $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$. If I take constant $w$ slices, I will get a $S^2$ for each $w\in[0,1]$ except at $w=0,1$ at which I get a single point (the 2-sphere has shrunk to a point). So if I allow for such singular surfaces, is it true that every 3-mfd is a surface bundle? This question has physical interest because it can be thought of as a big-bang, big-crunch scenario for a 2d spatial universe.

Comment: @dennis: The word "bundle" has a very precise meaning. You have to decide on your precise definition (so far, I do not see one) and post a new question.